# Cannot Connect to Docker postgres container - Scala

Tags: java, scala, docker, doobie

I have created a service called job-board I want it to run and talk to postgres container. I am not sure if I should run the job-board using sbt? or should I use docker-compose up to run both services with Docker?

When do you run with SBT and when running in containers?

I keep getting the below connection error, I have tried playing around with the connection urls but no luck.

I am unsure of how much role the application.config plays in all of this and how it relates to dockerFile and docker-compose.

Here is the github repo should you need more details: https://github.com/fullStackRyan/job-board

```
Starting job-board_postgres_1 ... done
Starting job-board_job-board_1 ... done
Attaching to job-board_postgres_1, job-board_job-board_1
postgres_1   | 
postgres_1   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres_1   | 
postgres_1   | 2020-08-13 10:57:43.540 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1   | 2020-08-13 10:57:43.540 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1   | 2020-08-13 10:57:43.542 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1   | 2020-08-13 10:57:43.555 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-13 10:57:29 UTC
postgres_1   | 2020-08-13 10:57:43.557 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
job-board_1  | [info] welcome to sbt 1.3.13 (Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0_222)
job-board_1  | [info] loading project definition from /usr/src/job-board/project
job-board_1  | [info] loading settings for project job-board from build.sbt ...
job-board_1  | [info] set current project to job-board (in build file:/usr/src/job-board/)
job-board_1  | [warn] insecure HTTP request is deprecated 'http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/'; switch to HTTPS or opt-in as ("Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
job-board_1  | [info] running io.github.jobboard.Main 
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.456 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - HikariPool-1 - configuration:
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.468 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - allowPoolSuspension.............false
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.468 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - autoCommit......................true
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.468 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - catalog.........................none
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.469 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionInitSql...............none
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.469 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTestQuery.............none
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.469 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTimeout...............30000
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.470 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSource......................none
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.470 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceClassName.............none
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.470 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceJNDI..................none
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.471 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.471 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - driverClassName.................none
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.471 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - healthCheckProperties...........{}
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.472 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - healthCheckRegistry.............none
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.472 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - idleTimeout.....................600000
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.472 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - initializationFailTimeout.......1
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.473 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - isolateInternalQueries..........false
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.473 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - jdbcUrl.........................postgres://admin:password@postgres:5432/job-board
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.473 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - leakDetectionThreshold..........0
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.474 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - maxLifetime.....................1800000
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.474 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - maximumPoolSize.................10
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.474 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - metricRegistry..................none
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.475 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - metricsTrackerFactory...........none
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.475 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - minimumIdle.....................10
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.475 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - password........................<masked>
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.476 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.476 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - readOnly........................false
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.476 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - registerMbeans..................false
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.476 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - scheduledExecutor...............none
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.477 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - schema..........................none
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.477 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - threadFactory...................internal
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.478 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - transactionIsolation............default
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.478 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - username........................"admin"
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.478 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - validationTimeout...............5000
job-board_1  | 10:57:57.482 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
job-board_1  | java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=postgres://admin:password@postgres:5432/job-board
job-board_1  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:112)
job-board_1  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:336)
job-board_1  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:109)
job-board_1  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:108)
job-board_1  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
job-board_1  |  at io.github.jobboard.database.Database$.transactor(Database.scala:20)
job-board_1  |  at io.github.jobboard.Main$$anonfun$1.apply(Main.scala:34)
job-board_1  |  at io.github.jobboard.Main$$anonfun$1.apply(Main.scala:33)
job-board_1  |  at fs2.Stream$$anonfun$flatMap$extension$1.apply(Stream.scala:1080)
job-board_1  |  at fs2.Stream$$anonfun$flatMap$extension$1.apply(Stream.scala:1073)
job-board_1  |  at fs2.internal.FreeC$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FreeC.scala:33)
job-board_1  |  at fs2.internal.FreeC$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FreeC.scala:30)
job-board_1  |  at fs2.internal.FreeC$ViewL$.mk(FreeC.scala:214)
job-board_1  |  at fs2.internal.FreeC$ViewL$.apply(FreeC.scala:206)
job-board_1  |  at fs2.internal.FreeC.viewL(FreeC.scala:67)
job-board_1  |  at fs2.internal.Algebra$.fs2$internal$Algebra$$go$1(Algebra.scala:214)
job-board_1  |  at fs2.internal.Algebra$$anonfun$fs2$internal$Algebra$$go$1$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(Algebra.scala:260)
job-board_1  |  at fs2.internal.Algebra$$anonfun$fs2$internal$Algebra$$interruptGuard$1$1.apply(Algebra.scala:230)
job-board_1  |  at fs2.internal.Algebra$$anonfun$fs2$internal$Algebra$$interruptGuard$1$1.apply(Algebra.scala:229)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.cats$effect$internals$IORunLoop$$loop(IORunLoop.scala:139)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.startCancelable(IORunLoop.scala:41)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.run(IOBracket.scala:86)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.cats$effect$internals$Trampoline$$immediateLoop(Trampoline.scala:70)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.startLoop(Trampoline.scala:36)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline.cats$effect$internals$TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline$$super$startLoop(TrampolineEC.scala:93)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline$$anonfun$startLoop$1.apply$mcV$sp(TrampolineEC.scala:93)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline$$anonfun$startLoop$1.apply(TrampolineEC.scala:93)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline$$anonfun$startLoop$1.apply(TrampolineEC.scala:93)
job-board_1  |  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline.startLoop(TrampolineEC.scala:92)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.execute(Trampoline.scala:43)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC.execute(TrampolineEC.scala:44)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.apply(IOBracket.scala:72)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.apply(IOBracket.scala:52)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.cats$effect$internals$IORunLoop$$loop(IORunLoop.scala:136)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.start(IORunLoop.scala:34)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(IOBracket.scala:44)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(IOBracket.scala:34)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.start(IORunLoop.scala:341)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.cats$effect$internals$IORunLoop$$loop(IORunLoop.scala:119)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.signal(IORunLoop.scala:355)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.apply(IORunLoop.scala:376)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.apply(IORunLoop.scala:316)
job-board_1  |  at cats.effect.internals.IOShift$Tick.run(IOShift.scala:36)
job-board_1  |  at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
job-board_1  |  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
job-board_1  |  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
job-board_1  |  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
job-board_1  |  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
job-board_1  | Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
job-board_1  |  at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
job-board_1  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:104)
job-board_1  |  ... 48 more
job-board_1  | 
job-board_1  | Exception: sbt.TrapExitSecurityException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "run-main-0"
job-board_1  | [error] Nonzero exit code: 1
job-board_1  | [error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code: 1
job-board_1  | [error] Total time: 4 s, completed Aug 13, 2020 10:57:57 AM
job-board_job-board_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: connecting to a database running in a docker container is the same as connecting with a local database. it's just a matter of ensuring the docker container has the ports open.
in production mode, you can run your scala app using docker as it makes some devops work easier. But if it's a small enough app, maybe you can just run as a scala app (heroku deals well with it for instance)

Answer (score 1):

Its look like your postgre url is wrong. According to this documentation I don`t see Postgre.POSTGRES_URL environment var. https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

In job-board: your POSTGRES_URL should look like
jdbc:{driver}://{host}:{port}/{db}

Comment: Thanks for the response. In your above comment, what does "driver" refer to in the URL, mine looks like this: "postgres://admin:password@postgres:5432/job-board" which I have put in docker-compose file and in my application.conf file.

Comment: If you read the [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html), it must respect JDBC URL format: `jdbc:postgresql://$HOST:$PORT/$DB`